# NullPointerException with libgdx using the gdx render() method

Tags: java, desktop-application, desktop, libgdx

Started making a game.
Here's some of my code.

```
package games.tribe.screens;

import games.tribe.model.World;
import games.tribe.view.WorldRenderer;

import com.badlogic.gdx.Gdx;
import com.badlogic.gdx.Screen;
import com.badlogic.gdx.graphics.GL10;

public class GameScreen implements Screen {

private World world;
private WorldRenderer renderer;

/** This was the bit I'd missed --------------------------------------**/
@Override
public void show() {
    world = new World();
    renderer = new WorldRenderer(world);
}
/**------------------------------------------------------------------**/

@Override
public void render(float delta) {
    Gdx.gl.glClearColor(0.1f, 0.1f, 0.1f, 1);
    Gdx.gl.glClear(GL10.GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT);
    renderer.render();
}

@Override
public void resize(int width, int height) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub


}

@Override
public void hide() {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

}

@Override
public void pause() {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

}

@Override
public void resume() {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

}

@Override
public void dispose() {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

}

}
```

here's the WorldRenderer Class:

```
package games.tribe.view;

import com.badlogic.gdx.graphics.Color;
import com.badlogic.gdx.graphics.OrthographicCamera;
import com.badlogic.gdx.graphics.glutils.ShapeRenderer;
import com.badlogic.gdx.graphics.glutils.ShapeRenderer.ShapeType;
import com.badlogic.gdx.math.Rectangle;

import games.tribe.model.Block;
import games.tribe.model.TribalHunter;
import games.tribe.model.World;

public class WorldRenderer {

private World world;
private OrthographicCamera cam;

/**for debug rendering**/
ShapeRenderer debugRenderer = new ShapeRenderer();

public WorldRenderer(World world) {
    this.world = world;
    this.cam = new OrthographicCamera(10, 7);
    this.cam.position.set(5, 3.5f, 0);
    this.cam.update();
}

public void render()  {
    //render blocks
    debugRenderer.setProjectionMatrix(cam.combined);
    debugRenderer.begin(ShapeType.Rectangle);
    for(Block block : world.getBlocks()) {
        Rectangle rect = block.getBounds();
        float x1 = block.getPosition().x + rect.x;
        float y1 = block.getPosition().y + rect.y;
        debugRenderer.setColor(new Color(1, 0, 0, 1));
        debugRenderer.rect(x1, y1, rect.width, rect.height);
    }
    //render hunter
    TribalHunter hunter = world.getHunter();
    Rectangle rect = hunter.getBounds();
    float x1 = hunter.getPosition().x + rect.x;
    float y1 = hunter.getPosition().y + rect.y;
    debugRenderer.setColor(new Color(0, 1, 0, 1));
    debugRenderer.rect(x1, y1, rect.width, rect.height);
    debugRenderer.end();

}
}
```

This is the exception I'm getting when I run it as a desktop application:

```
Exception in thread "LWJGL Application" java.lang.NullPointerException
at games.tribe.screens.GameScreen.render(GameScreen.java:19)
at com.badlogic.gdx.Game.render(Game.java:46)
at com.badlogic.gdx.backends.lwjgl.LwjglApplication.mainLoop(LwjglApplication.java:202)
at com.badlogic.gdx.backends.lwjgl.LwjglApplication$1.run(LwjglApplication.java:131)
AL lib: ReleaseALC: 1 device not closed
```

Line 46 of gdx.Game.render is this method:

```
@Override
public void render () {
    if (screen != null) screen.render(Gdx.graphics.getDeltaTime());
}
```

Any help will be appreciated

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In the `GameScreen`'s `render()` method, has the `renderer` been initialized?  That could be causing the problem if it hasn't.

**Edit:** The problem you're having, according to the top two lines of the error, is a `NullPointerException` on line `19` of the class `GameScreen`.  The `NullPointerException` only occurs when an object is used for some action when the object itself is `null` because it likely hasn't been initialized.

Line `19` of the `GameScreen` is:

```
renderer.render();
```

...but the object `renderer` has not been initialized anywhere, so it is currently `null` which is the default.  To avoid getting this error, you'll need to initialize the `renderer` object before you run that line of code.  Perhaps with something like this:

```
@Override
public void render(float delta) {
    Gdx.gl.glClearColor(0.1f, 0.1f, 0.1f, 1);
    Gdx.gl.glClear(GL10.GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT);

    renderer = new WorldRenderer();
    renderer.render();
}
```

I am not familiar with libgdx, so I can't be sure that's exactly how a `WorldRenderer` is initialized, but you need to do something of the sort.  I hope this helps.

Comment: I thought everything had been initialized correctly. I've editted the code to show the the whole code for both classes.

Comment: Oh ofcourse! You were right :) initialised them (see editted question)

Comment: Ah, I just saw that you figured it out after I edited. Oh well, I hope you enjoy the overly detailed explanation.  Glad I could help.